# mui5: tabs: Issue with MUI Typography: max-width for display none setting as zero

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI5 and loading the Tabs with Material-react-table in each tab. Initially there is not data in the tables

```
<MDBox sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <MDBox sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
    <Tabs
      value={valueTab}
      onChange={handleChange}
      textColor="secondary"
      indicatorColor="secondary"
    >
      <Tab label="Incoming" {...hare0} />
      <Tab label="Outgoing" {...hare1} />
    </Tabs>
  </MDBox>
  <div
    role="tabpanel"
    hidden={valueTab !== 0}
    id="simple-tabpanel-0"
    aria-labelledby="simple-tab-0"
  >
    <MaterialReactTableComponent />
  </div>
  <div
    role="tabpanel"
    hidden={valueTab !== 1}
    id="simple-tabpanel-1"
    aria-labelledby="simple-tab-1"
  >
    <MaterialReactTableComponent />
  </div>
</MDBox>
```

Both the tables i am loading are empty both shows `No records to Display`

The first tab shows the `No records to Display`  properly but the other one not

[image]

[image]

where as the second shows `No records to Display` vertically

[image]

[image]

[image]